# how to fix issue with images link on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i have 3 images they all are using the same code with different style of course first image is on left second image is in middle and third is on right.

```
bottom: 10;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
text-align: center; 
margin: 0px auto;
```

okay so the issue i'm having is when you are to hover on the image it can only hover the pointer on either top part of the image but when hovering over the image on bottom then it detects no link at all.

sample of code for image I'm using

```
<a href="/"><img style="width: 130px; height: 130px; border: 0px; display: inline;" src="img">
</a>
```

All of the images are different sizes but one the first image i resized the image to like 150px width and 100 width height then the hover start working but i want the image to be hover on 100px width and 50px height and when i do that it only hovers over right side of the image and this image is the first image on left. Second image i tried resizing but it only hovers on top of the image. any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: can you please create a jsFiddle highlighting your problem?

Comment: Wait... what? Can you create a jsfiddle or at least provide all of your code? Edit: I'm guessing your issue is that you have your `<img>` tag set to `display:inline` but I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: its weird i know i think it might be one of the css code could be causing this but i just can't figure it out

Comment: you showed some css but not the selector. We have no idea what it applies to. Also not clear at all what your problem is

Comment: here is http://jsfiddle.net/1hwm3epj/

Comment: if you were to hover on the image you will see the results :( it just has the pointer but you can't click on it unless you move the mouse around and around and then you will be able to click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your CSS. All of your `<div>`'s containing the anchor tags and the images have a `fixed` position along with `left: 0` which is why they are overlapping. You can achieve what you're trying to do like this, I've modified the `HTML` and added new CSS:

```css
#images {
    text-align: center;
}

#images a:nth-child(2) {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

#images a:last-child {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="images"><a href="#"target="_blank"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 0;" src="http://7brands.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/google-maps-logo.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"target="_blank"><img style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 0;" src="http://7brands.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/google-maps-logo.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"target="_blank"><img style="width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 0;" src="http://7brands.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/google-maps-logo.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Comment: on the third image I'm embedding some content along with the image so if i was to use the original code just for third image will that cause problems as well?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly your need, from my understand you can do it as follow:
Add this css styles and hover the image:

```
#img1 {
bottom: 10;
left:0;
right:0;
position: fixed;
text-align:center;
margin: 0px auto
z-index:1;
}

 #img1 img:hover {
width:100px !important;
height:50px !important;}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/1hwm3epj/16/